# Toggle textarea text, but retain changes to the text

Tags: javascript, textarea, toggle

I'm trying to use a checkbox to disable and enable a textarea, toggling text in the box at the same time. My only issue is that I can't retain the changes that I make when the textarea is enabled. The textarea is disabled initially and holds initial text. After the textarea is enabled, the text becomes editable. If the checkbox is re-checked, the changes disappear and the orginal text re-appears-- toggling back removes the changes (which is not what I want). I'd like to toggle the text back and forth, but without removing the changes. I believe that the best way to do this is to retain the changes in a variable? I've copied the code below:

```
 function toggleDisabled(_checked) {
document.getElementById('tjh').disabled = _checked ? true : false;
document.getElementById('tjh').value= "initial text";
}

    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="name1"     onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked)"/>
<textarea disabled name="name2" id="tjh">initial text</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: why change the value at all during the process?

Comment: They would have to be able to go back to that original text, if they decided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the value from the `textarea` and store it into a variable every time the checkbox is checked or unchecked.  You also don't need to (or should) set the initial value for the `textarea` in your javascript.  Set the initial `textarea` content in the HTML and then use javascript to attach event listener to the checkbox that will add/remove the `disabled` attribute from the element based on whether checked or not.

You can use the `onChange` attribute on the HTML element and pass in a javascript function as you originally had, but IMO doing so unnecessarily couples the HTML and Javascript together; making it harder to make changes and read.

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" checked name="name1" id='name1' />
  <textarea disabled name="name2" id="tjh">Initial text</textarea>
</form>



<script type='text/javascript'>
  
  // Grab HTML elements by element's id
  var txtBox = document.getElementById('tjh');
  var checkBox = document.getElementById('name1');
  var customText = 'initial text';

  // Attach event listener to checkbox
  checkBox.addEventListener('click', function(evt, el) {

    // If checked, then save current textarea value and disable textarea
    if (evt.target.checked) {
      customText = txtBox.value;
      txtBox.value = 'initial text';
      txtBox.setAttribute('disabled', evt.target.checked);
    }

    // Otherwise restore text and reenable the textarea by removing disabled attribute from HTML element
    else {
      txtBox.value = customText ;
      txtBox.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }, false)
</script>
```

EDIT: Added customText variable to store/restore txtBox values on disable/enable of checkbox

Comment: Thanks James, I just ran this and it might be something I can work through. There is a need to recheck the box and get the initial text again. Un-checking again should show the edited text?

Comment: If your trying to show "initial text" text when the `textarea` is disabled and then restore the edited text when the `textarea` is enabled again, you can declare a variable underneath `checkBox` variable (call it `customText`) and then write `if (checked) { customText = txtBox.value; txtBox.value = "initial text" } else { txtBox.value = customText; }` inside the `if-else` statement

Comment: can you update your code, I'm sure it'll work and then I can mark it as the answer. Thanks, I don't want to skip the answer if you've got it.

Comment: I updated the code so that disabling the checkbox will restore changed `textarea` value and enabling the checkbox will restore the initial value

Comment: Thanks so much, if you are interested in answering one more question: I have 20 textarea boxes that I have to code for... is getElementById the only way, or can I target class name instead. getElementByClassName doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @coder1989 You can use `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");` which is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, can't you just store the text in a variable?

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer because I cannot do so with a comment.

Comment: I understood. I'm thinking that I'd need help with this, considering the trouble I've had with this step. Any examples would be a push in the right path.

Comment: Since I don't work with JS much (I just know the logic), I think you could create a variable "textStorage". When the checkbox is clicked (is there an event for that?) set textStorage to equal to textBox.getText or something like that.